# Firefox sync without browser restart and external services

Tags: firefox, firefox-sync

I have several machines ( work / home / laptop ) running on debian sid with the same version firefox.

I want to sync open tabs, bookmarks and installed plugins without firefox restart ( it's really annoying to restart it every time I return home from work and vice versa ). No history or cookies / passwords sync is required.

There are several options for sync:

- firefox sync ( requires external server usage, that I do not trust )
- settings directory ( ~/.mozilla/firefox ) sync ( firefox restart is required )
- various plugins ( requires restart or I didn't search carefully )

Is there a way to sync without tabs restart?

There is direct access via ssh ( any other ways also may be shared ) between all these machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of fact, you can [run your own Firefox Sync server](http://docs.services.mozilla.com/howtos/run-sync.html). Any kind of synchronization is going to require **something** that's on at the time you want to sync. You could also look at some plugins, but they are going to do just that: upload your data **somewhere** so the other computer can download your stuff.